# PHP CURL Enable Linux

Tags: php, curl

I have some php scripts that I've been running on an Apache server on a windows machine. These scripts use curl which isn't enabled by default in php. For windows enabling it was as easy and un-commenting the line with the curl .dll file in the php.ini file. Well since Linux uses .so instead of .dll files that wont work.

Does anyone have any idea how to enable curl on an Apache server running on a Linux machine? Php is already installed so I'm really hoping for a solution that doesn't involve re-installing php. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to install the needed package if not already installed.

On ubuntu, you just type:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

RPM-based distribution should have a similar package name like `yum install` for fedora and centos.

Comment: I didn't setup the server but it looks like it is running openSUSE v. 11.3.  I'm interacting with it over commandline only.

Comment: You can use `Yast` to install the needed package. It is really a powerful system tool and its interface can be shown also in the command line (text-based) environment.